# Visualizing Apache Cassandra's data using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, kibana

I have a multinode apache Cassandra, full of data and I want to visualize the data using Kibana. What is the best way for such situation? I've read about Elassandra, but I couldn't understand Elassandra is a plugin that should be installed on my Cassandra cluster or it is a separate independent tool (I guess the latest is true), if so, Cause I store all of my data in Cassandra, I couldn't use that!

Any suggestion for connecting Apache Cassandra to Kibana and visualize its data, will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with packetbeat plugin. Follow below link for reference. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/packetbeat-configuration.html